# NSIS installer opens up in the background

Tags: uac, nsis

I have an NSIS installer that requires UAC elevation. When my setup.exe is executed through Chrome or IE, the UAC elevation dialog is displayed, but when the user confirms, Chrome comes back to the front and the installer is opened behind it.

It's worth nothing that I am using the UAC plugin (0.2.2c) and that bug was discussed a bit [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk%3aUAC_plug-in), but even if I remove all traces of the plugin, the problem persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Does a simple test installer with just "RequestExecutionLevel admin" have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with invoking the inetc plugin in the .OnInit problem. See the examples [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in).

Answer (score 0):

I have never verified this but I believe there could be a race condition when a NSIS installer starts up (Between the verification/CRC dialog closing and the first page of the "real" dialog starting up) If my assumption is correct, there could be a short period at startup where there is no visible window and foreground focus would go somewhere else.

Hopefully the UAC plugin will be updated soon... (There is no window in .onInit so that is why it has problems)

Comment: Is there any command in NSIS that could bring it to the foreground again?

Comment: Not really, NSIS has the BringToFront command, but it will most likely just flash the taskbar, once you lose focus, you can't really regain it (without ugly hacks)